# Accelerometer interface and the GPS when I push a button in Xcode

Tags: xcode, button, gps, accelerometer

I will like to have the values at once of the Accelerometer interface and the GPS when I push a button in Xcode.

I know now about the singleton concept, but I do not know how to launch the Accelerometer and the GPS by pushing a single button.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to add the interfaces required a bit like this :

```
@interface OverlayViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```